# Changing date formats and calculating duration using lubridate

Tags: r, parsing, lubridate

I am trying to get the duration between issue_d and last_pymnt_d in my dataset using the lubridate package. issue_d is in the following formatting chr  "2015-05-01T00:00:00Z" and last_pymnt_d is in chr  "Feb-2017". I need them in the same format (just need "my" or "myd" is fine if "my" is not an option) Then I need to know calculate between issue_d and last_pymnt_d.

```
lcDataSet2$issue_d<-parse_date_time(lcDataSet2$issue_d, "myd")
```

turns my issue_d into NA. I also get the below error when even just trying to view last_pymnt_d in date format

```
as.Date(lcRawData$last_pymnt_d)
```

```
    Error in charToDate(x) : 
    character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How can I get these into the same date format and then calculate the duration?

Answer (score 2):

The `zoo` package gives you a function `as.yearmon` to covert dates into `yearmon` objects containing only the month and year. Since your `last_pymnt_d` is only month and year, the best date difference you will get is number of months:

```
library(zoo)
issue_d <- "2015-05-01T00:00:00Z"
last_pymnt_d <- "Feb-2017"

diff <- as.yearmon(last_pymnt_d, format = "%b-%Y") - as.yearmon(as.Date(issue_d))
diff
1.75
```

Under the hood, the `yearmon` object is a number of years, with the decimal component representing the months. A difference in `yearmon` of 1.75 is 1 year and 9 months.

```
diff_months <- paste(round(diff * 12, 0), "months")
"21 months"
diff_yearmon <- paste(floor(diff), "years and", round((diff %% 1) * 12, 0), "months")
diff_yearmon
"1 years and 9 months"
```

Comment: Should point out that the last payment date was changed to `Feb 2017` from the provided date of `Feb-2017` which returns `NA` without a specified format string.

Comment: @manotheshark  Oh! I did not even realize what I did there. Good catch.

Comment: @manotheshark @Ben Norris Thank you! I am able to transform issue_d but last_pymnt_d is coming up as NAs with this command ```last_pymnt_d <- as.yearmon(lcDataSet2$last_pymnt_d)```. I

Comment: @CourtneyVadnais - I made a small edit to my answer, based on manotheshark's `zoo` code. Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 2):

The order and letter case of the format string is important for parsing dates.

```
library(lubridate)

parse_date_time('2015-05-01T00:00:00Z', 'Y-m-d H:M:S')
[1] "2015-05-01 UTC"

parse_date_time('Feb-2017', 'b-Y')
[1] "2017-02-01 UTC"
```

If wanting just the month and year there is a `zoo` function

```
library(zoo)

date1 <- as.yearmon('2015-05-01T00:00:00Z')
[1] "May 2015"

date2 <- as.yearmon('Feb-2017', '%b-%Y')
[1] "Feb 2017"

difftime(date2, date1)
Time difference of 642 days
```